# Impossible to get the Grouping columns (count) if the RowCount button from the UI in Salesforce report is Unchecked

Tags: apex, callout, apexrest, reports-api

I am hitting this rest API end point in Apex in order to get Salesforce Report Data.

```java
String dash_url = '/services/data/v35.0/analytics/reports/'+repId+'?includeDetails=true';
```

It fetches me result and I have the logic in mind in order to create a table to replicate the exact report.

While I was analysing JSON I found one very strange issue or maybe it is designed due to some logic while I am not able to get.

**The Issue:** If you open any report in lightning in Salesforce you will find at the bottom a Record Count Toggle button. If it is checked I get the data fairly very easy for my groupings (count of each grouping entry in order to calculate row span).

But when the above toggle is unchecked then that count is not available which is very strange nowhere in the whole JSON it is to be found

**Example JSON below**

```js
"factMap": {
   "0!T": {
     "aggregates": [
       {
         "label": "USD 144,945,892.54",
         "value": 144945892.5364451
       },
       {
         "label": "68",
         "value": 68
       },
       {
         "label": "USD 144,945,892.54",
         "value": 144945892.5364451
       },
       {
         "label": "5",
         "value": 5
       },
       {
         "label": "42",
         "value": 42
       }
```

**This is the result when the toggle button is checked**

```js
"factMap": {
    "0!T": {
      "aggregates": [
        {
          "label": "USD 144,945,892.54",
          "value": 144945892.5364451
        },
        {
          "label": "68",
          "value": 68
        },
        {
          "label": "USD 144,945,892.54",
          "value": 144945892.5364451
        },
        {
          "label": "5",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "label": "42",
          "value": 42
        },
        {
          "label": "23",
          "value": 23
        }
```

The last entry above JSON is count of that aggregate cell in my table. It would be needed in order to calculate rowspan when I create a html.

Any help here would work because even if I find a logic to calculate it manually it would simply break for complex report tables and 2000 records only this would work if the row count is coming as it is.

Comment: I am not sure about the use case of pulling report data into analytics, but you might be able to reproduce the report using SOQL, allowing you to control the output.

REST API does not currently provide an option to override the Record Count setting in the report definition through the API request. Alternatively, if possible, you could modify the report always to have the Record Count option turned on.

Comment: @VijayaKapadam how do you query report metadata with rest Api? By metadata I mean its rows? ALso, the use case is simple salesforce provides a Email report subscription functionality to Email we are replicating that with custom apex code because of some restrictions for us to use email subscription functionality and also its limitations.

Thanks.

Comment: You can get report metadata using
Example: /services/data/v29.0/analytics/reports/00OD0000001ZbP7MAK/describe

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportmetadata.htm